# Conditional nested filters in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model, lets say:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
   last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

And, exists a search form, where I can search rows whether by first_name, by last_name or by both. I have noted that I can link filters in a django queryset, e.g:

```
def search(request):
   list = Person.objects.filter(first_name= val1).filter(last_name=val2)
```

But what if one of the values val1, val2 is null? Should I do something like:

```
def searh(request):
   if val1 != null and val2 == null:
      list = Person.objects.filter(first_name= val1)
   if val2 == null and val2 != null:
       list = Person.objects.filter(last_name= val2)
   if val2 != null and val2 != null:
       list = Person.objects.filter(first_name= val1).filter(last_name=val2)
```

Is there any direct way to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def search(request, val1, val2):
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    if val1:
        persons = persons.filter(first_name=val1)
    if val2:
        persons = persons.filter(last_name=val2)
    return persons
```

This works (isn't inefficient) because [Querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

Comment: I was hoping that there's any way to pass a array of conditions to the filter function hehe. Thanks!! It should work. But what if exists rows that doesn't match with the first criteria (val1) and match with the second criteria (val2)? Those rows won't be in persons after the first "if"?

Comment: of course you can always filter for more than criterion at once: `persons.filter(first_name=val1, last_name=val2)`. This returns only results that match _all_ criteria. The documentation explains complex lookups (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) that allow for queries that match _any_ criterion (and more).

Answer (score 5):

*(Disclaimer: tested in Python 2.7, Django 1.6, although it should work in general)*

I've been recently introduced to the following construct that directly applies to OP's issue:

```
def search(request, val1, val2):
    filter_args={}
    if val1:
        filter_args["first_name"]=val1
    if val2:
        filter_args["last_name"]=val2

    persons = Person.objects.filter(**filter_args)

    return persons
```

Basically, this will construct a filter with more than one criterion, even if you don't know a-priori whether both `val1` and `val2` will be available. It'll construct the most specific filter using conjunction (`and`) it can, without needing extra logic evaluation to overcome the fact that `.filter(...).filter(...)` always evaluates the criterions using disjunction (`or`). If later you want to add `age` to your conjunction, for instance, just add the following two lines (and `val3` to the function argument list):

```
    if val3:
        filter_args["age"]=val3
```

I'm using this methodology in a project I'm working on to great success, and thought this information might be useful to newer Django users with this same question.